# How to get python function return value from URL?

Tags: python, html, flask

I use flask to make web server.

in html,

```
<body>
  {{ url_for('test1') }}
</body>
```

in python,

```
def test2():
   str = "sample!"
   yield str

@app.route("/test1")
def test1():
   return Response(test2())
```

I wanna show this on html page as string
but the result is '/test1'
what should I do?

Not render_template please..

Comment: Where do you request the `/test1` URL? Do you want to show the contents of the response? Are you doing an ajax request to `http://python/test1`? `url_for(x)` means, "give me the url of the named route "x". It's probably not what you want. What is your expectation?

Comment: I'm beginner in web coding. I want to get the str data ("sample!") to html page. but I don't know javascript... need help

Comment: The best resource for stuff like that is the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest